# Exiting a shell script if certain child processes exit

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a Bash script that starts one web server, does some work, and then starts a second web server. I would like the script to exit, and for both of these servers to be terminated, if either server exits or the user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

What I have now looks like this:

```
start_server_1 &
server_1_pid=$!

trap "kill $server_1_pid" EXIT

# ...do some work that requires server 1 to be running...

start_server_2 || exit $?
```

This correctly shuts down both servers if the user types <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. If Server 1 exits, however, then Server 2 and the script itself continue to run. How can I make sure that both servers and the script will be taken down if one of these processes exits?

Comment: Can you run the servers such that they do not fork? That should make them more trackable by a simple shell script.

Comment: @thrig I want to run two servers simultaneously from one script, so I assume I need to run at least one of them in the background…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run both processes in the background, then [`wait -n`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-wait) to wait for one of them to exit.

Bash doesn't report back which process exited, but you can run [`jobs -p`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-jobs) to get the list of background jobs that are still running and kill them.

```
start_server_1 &
server_1_pid=$!
start_server_2 &
server_2_pid=$!
wait -n
kill $(jobs -p)
```

`wait -n` is new in bash 4.3. In older versions, doing this is much more difficult.

Other common shells don't have `wait -n`, but they instead let you set a trap on SIGCHLD and call plain `wait`. In dash, ksh93, mksh and zsh, you can write

```
trap 'kill $server_1_pid $server_2_pid; exit' CHLD
wait
```

This doesn't work in bash because there the SIGCHLD trap is only invoked after all jobs have finished running.